# How to count total row on MySQL based upon month and year

Tags: mysql, database, select, group-by, count

My database table contains value in this way
[IMAGE FOR TABLE DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9da0u.png)

I want to track down same email which has been used more than one times for a particular month and year.
In the above scenario, email that has been repeated multiple times was *sandeshphuya@gmail.com*, *jes@gmail.com* and *ramu@gmail.com* for different months. **I want to track down customer repetition following their email for each month and year.**

The query that I am using right now is

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booked_on, '%Y-%m') as monthYear, email,
COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
FROM 'tablename'
GROUP BY email,DATE_FORMAT(booked_on, '%Y-%m') HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY `booked_on`;
```

`GROUP BY` email was used as it generates the repeated email and `GROUP BY` `DATE_FORMAT(booked_on, '%Y'-%m')` was used to track down total email repeated for each month/year.

This prints out data as

[IMAGE FOR SELECT QUERY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5qaH.png)

How can I track down total repeated email following month and year? The expected result is

[RESULT EXPECTED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8RpG.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your query as a subquery for a new group by:

```
select sub.monthYear,count(*)
from
    (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booked_on, '%Y-%m') as monthYear, 
            email,
            COUNT(*) AS 'Count'
     FROM 'tablename'
     GROUP BY email,DATE_FORMAT(booked_on, '%Y-%m') 
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
     ORDER BY `booked_on`) as sub
GROUP BY sub.monthYear
```

Comment: But you probably need `SUM()` in stead of `COUNT()` in you first line ?

Comment: @Luuk, No, if you use sum(`Count`), you would get the total number of repetitions, but the OP needs the number of emails repeated, so the number of rows in the subquery

Comment: ok, that part was unclear to /me from the question.... (language problem in my side )

Comment: Luuk I used my old query and counted the number of row manually which says 9 and when I used the query provided by @nacho it says total as 9. So the query provided by nacho is CORRECT.